# php pdo dynamic dropdown not insering correct value into db

Tags: php, mysql

hoping someone can help me out. I am trying to insert into a mysql db a value that a user selects from a dynamic dropdown

i can get the dynamic drop down to list the values properly. the table that the dynamic dropdown data comes from has 2 colums (fruit_id, FruitType) ... there are a total of 4 fruits currently listed in this table (and in my dropdown)

what I would like to do is display this drop down in a form and once a user selects a fruit, i would like to insert the (fruit_id) value of the selected fruit into another mysql table

here is what i have so far, for some reason no matter what I select in the dropdown the (fruit_id) that gets inserted is 4 (ps, I only have 4 fruits in my table/dropdown)

this is the code that I have so far, any suggestions are appreciated. thanks :)

```
<?php

require_once('../../../connect.php');


    //  dropdown
        $fruit_type = '';
        $sql = "SELECT fruit_id, FruitType from mydb.mytbl";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($results as $row) { 
            $fruit_type.= '<option value="' . $row["fruit_id"] . '">' . $row["FruitType"] . '</option>';

        }



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



    $errors = array();
    require('validate.php');



    if(!count($errors)){

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO fruittable
                    (fruit_id)
                VALUES ('".$row['fruit_id']."'); 
            ";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

    }

} 



if(isset($result)){
    if($result){

    }else{
        echo '<b>Unable to Insert</b>';
        print '<pre>'.print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true);
    }
}


?>

<h1>Log Fruit</h1>
<form method="post" action="add.php">

    fruit type <br/>
    <select name="fruit_select"> 
    <option value=""</option>
    <?php echo $fruit_type;?> <br/>
    </select>
    <p></p>



    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />

</form>
```

Comment: Just to let you know: dynamic dropdowns never insert anything in db. Actually, there is no way to tell a dropdown even database password.

Comment: Besides, a question like "please read my code, formulate a question and answer it as well" considered offtopic.

Comment: And just to let you know again, you are using PDO wrong way. It is adwised to read some tutorials before use.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why are you removing MySQL-related tags from many questions?

Comment: Well, actually I removed PDO tag, while MySQL remains in place (though it's irrelevant too). I am removing tags which I find wrongly put.

Comment: @YourCommonSense But this code does use PDO.

Comment: The way this code uses PDO is of no use, its still extremely vulnerable to injection that INSERT

Comment: it also does use some web-server, computer hardware, HTTP protocol, HTML language, various PHP commands which have their own respective tags. Why you preferred PDO over them? Tags should be relevant to the problem, not just reflect some technologies you happen to use along.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Then what would you have the tags pdo and mysqli be used for?

Comment: For the problems with PDO and mysql respectively. By the way, the ability to separate realms will help you a lot. Not only with properly tagging but with solving problems you have. PDO has nothing to do with broken HTML. As soon as you learn it, it will let you to focus on the real problem.

Comment: Instead of asking me, better ask yourself, what **particular** problem with PDO (or mysqli) you have. If you can't why do you think any of these tags relevant to your question?

Comment: @YourCommonSense What question? You haven't edited mine! FYI, I have a GreaseMonkey script I use to tag SO users; I tagged you as a busybody so I can keep an eye on your edits. Also, please use `@` so people don't have to refresh the page to discover your responses.

Comment: 1. The question " what particular problem with PDO (or mysqli) you have?". 2. I don't care. 3. I am writing a comment under your post - so, you're notified without  no @s.

Comment: No, I would be notified only if it were a comment under my question or answer or if it were your question or answer and I was the only other person in the conversation. You won't be notified about this, for example.

Comment: @Boann oh, just noticed that you are not the OP, as I thought all the time. So, you may ignore my last few comments. I've answered you already though, hope you find it satisfactory. If no - feel free to ask if something remained unclear to you

Comment: @yourcommonsense - you are a complete jack ass. if i had tagged the question under something like ajax or java ... yes the tag would not be appropriate. however my script was based on html/php/mysql/pdo which is what i tagged it for. second off if i knew what the hell the source of the problem was i would be able to narrow it down more and even maybe fix it. point is i didn't know and as far as i was concerned it could have been any of the things that i tagged it under.

Comment: @yourcommonsense .. all you are doing is removing relevant tags and making it more difficult for people to find questions. people who actually want to help by proving guidance on the answer ... hell you posted a dozen replies how the code was way off but did not even throw out one suggestion (bitching doesn't qualify).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed your PDO.  you have to bind the parameters in PDO.

Here is how you would have the code display each option:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../connect.php');

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $fruitid=$_POST['fruit_select'];
    $insertsql = "INSERT INTO fruittable (fruit_id) VALUES (:fruitid)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($insertsql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fruitid', $fruitid);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$fruit_type = '';
$sql = "SELECT fruit_id, FruitType FROM table";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
?>

<h1>Log Fruit</h1>
<form method="post" action="add.php">
    fruit type <br/>
    <select name="fruit_select"> 
    <option value=""</option>
    <?php    
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
        echo "<option value='".$row['fruit_id']."'>".$row['FruitType']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />

</form>
```

Using this code in a page called add.php should do what you are wanting.  It will list the fruits and whenever you select a fruit and click Add/Submit button it'll add it to the database.

Comment: I changed my code to tell him what was wrong and also added how he can insert the value to the database, like his original question intended to ask.

Comment: I had never heard of .= before.  I learned something today :-) that's what it's all about!  I changed my answer again.  Thank you for catching my mistakes and teaching me something!

Comment: @YourCommonSense does that seem appropriate now?

Comment: oh. If you'd like that learning business, there is quite a ton. but you'll save both us great lot of time if you create a test project on your local server (surely you have one) with fruits table and try to run your code. I still can see two problems with this code, one is from the OP and one you introduced yourself. But I am only a human and surely may overlook many others. So, the only way to tell if some code works, is to run it. I am using this method all the way answering questions on SO, and find it extremely useful.

Comment: I tested it and it works.  I did find one mistake in my code but have fixed it.

Comment: dareshull, i would rate your comment up but i need a min 15 reputation which i don't have :( ... ps i did change $stmt->bindParam(':fruitid', $fruitid);  to $stmt->bindParam(':fruitid', $fruitid, PDO::PARAM_INT); but either way thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: dareshull = darekshull :)

Comment: Thanks @chemicaluser for checking it as correct!  I hope you have fun with your script!